# How to turn off the mesh renderer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to turn off the mesh renderer of the sphere when x==3 and y==3, but that sphere is defined in another file (gem.cs).  I want the mesh renderer to turn off in a different .cs file named as board.cs. I just want to make this gem(cube) have a sphere inside it to be invisible.  How can I do it?

**board.cs**

```
public List<Gem> gems = new List<Gem>();
    public int GridWidth;
    public int GridHeight;
    public GameObject gemprefab;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

       for (int  y = 0; y<GridHeight; y++) { 
                 for (int x= 0; x<GridHeight; x++) {


          GameObject g =  Instantiate(gemprefab, new Vector3 (x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    g.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
                    gems.Add(g.GetComponent<Gem>());


          if(y==3 && x==3)
          { //   eslot=new Vector3 (3, 3, 0) as GameObject;

              gemprefab.renderer.enabled = false;


          }

          }
          }
       gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (-1.453695f, -1.409445f, 0);


    }
```

**Gem.cs**

```
public GameObject sphere;
    string[] gemMats ={"Red","Blue","Green","Orange","Yellow","Black","Purple"};
    string color="";
    public bool isSelected=false;
    public List<Gem>Neighbors = new List<Gem>();

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

       CreateGem ();
    }
    public void CreateGem()
    {
       color = gemMats[Random.Range(0,gemMats.Length)];
       Material m =Resources.Load("Materials/"+color) as Material; 
       sphere.renderer.material =m;



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public List<Gem> gems = new List<Gem>();
    public int GridWidth;
    public int GridHeight;
    public GameObject gemprefab;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

       for (int  y = 0; y<GridHeight; y++) { 
                 for (int x= 0; x<GridHeight; x++) {


          GameObject g =  Instantiate(gemprefab, new Vector3 (x, y, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    g.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
                    gemComponent = g.GetComponent<Gem>();
                    gems.Add(gemComponent);


          if(y==3 && x==3)
          { //   eslot=new Vector3 (3, 3, 0) as GameObject;

              //gemprefab.renderer.enabled = false;
              gemComponent.sphere.renderer.enabled = false;

          }

          }
          }
       gameObject.transform.position = new Vector3 (-1.453695f, -1.409445f, 0);


    }
```